# How to replace words in a sentence with its values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, replace

I have the following scenerio , where I have the following string

```
Edit:  const message = results.doc.data().taskSettings.taskInProgressSettings.pushNotifications.onAssignmentNotifyEmployee.message;
```

I get the message from db , and the variables are not necessarily `taskId , customerName` . It can be `taskId , customerName , customerId, taskCreaterName , employeeName , employeeId`. The message may contain any of the above variables and i need to replace them in run time with its values.

```
message:`Task ${taskId} assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName}`
let taskId = T-100;
let taskCreaterName = 'mark';
let customerName = 'henry';
```

and I want to replace the variables (taskId , taskCreaterName , customername) with its values and the final result should be the following,

```
newMessage = Task T-100 assigned by mark for customer henry
```

What would be the best way of achieving this. Thanks

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? Just place message line at bottom

Comment: when you say `let taskId = T-100;` do you want the literal string `T-100` to be parsed into the string, or you want the expression result `T minus 100`?

Comment: like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQMzGJ

Comment: @Sagar The message is dynamic from db and Iam not able to replace the variables with its values in run time.

Comment: @ShaikNizamuddin https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQMzGJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work in generic way you can keep 1 object (like 'withData' I created below, rather than maintaining different variables) to store values to replace and let generic function (replace) take care of all the changes like below

```js
let message = 'Task ${taskId} assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName}'

let withData = {
  taskId: 'T-100'
  , taskCreaterName: 'mark'
  , customerName: 'henry'
}

function replace(obj, withData) {
  let result = message.slice(0)
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(withData)) {
    result = result.replace('${' + key + '}', value)
  }
  
  return result
}

let result = replace(message, withData)

console.log(result)

// In case Object.entries is not supported
function replace(obj, withData) {
  let result = message.slice(0)
  for (let key in withData) {
    let value = withData[key]
    result = result.replace('${' + key + '}', value)
  }
  
  return result
}
```

Comment: Iam getting the following error : Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: Okay. Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome browser and its firebase

Comment: No problem, may be your chrome needs update. Never mind updated my answer and you can now use it without "object.entries". pls check

Comment: I am used to "for..of" that's why always prefer to work ES6 way, still you can anyday use "for..in"

Comment: Sir , Iam working on it ,and definitely I will update you. thanks

Comment: It is replacing only the first variable 
'`Task TSK-0009 assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customername}`'

Comment: You can click on "Run Code Snippet" to verify it's replacing all words. Pls can show what you are using exactly.

Comment: Pls make sure "key" names are exactly the same. Only then it will replace it

Comment: Thanks sir its working . previoulsy the keys didnt matched for rest of the variables

Comment: Great!! Pls drop "sir" as we all are learners and friends here!! Also, pls mark this answer as accepted solution so that others get to know your issue is resolved!! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can store values with target names in object and use `.replace()` to replacing target part of string with values in object. If value with matched name exist in object replace it with value.

```js
var message = 'Task ${taskId} assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName} and ${newVar}';
var values = {
  taskId: 'T-100',
  taskCreaterName: 'mark',
  customerName: 'henry'
};
var newStr = message.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, function(match, cont){
  return typeof values[cont] !== 'undefined' ? values[cont] : match;
})
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: @ShaikNizamuddin i think this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Js will replace the variables with value at runtime.

Comment: need to check on the support for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, for instance this will not work in IE

Comment: When i see logs before and after , I get the same sentence with no changes

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way to accomplish the thing you're looking for:

```
let taskId = 'T-100';
let taskCreaterName = 'mark';
let customerName = 'henry';

let newMessage = 'Task ' + taskId + ' assigned by ' + taskCreaterName + ' for customer ' + customerName;
```

Where newMessage has "Task T-100 assigned by mark for customer henry".

Comment: OP mentioned that message comes from db and is dynamic

Comment: Well, OP edited the question after I posted my answer. I answered his original question just fine.

Comment: It was in comment before you answered

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the value of `T` in your code, which you did not provide, I will assume it holds a valid Integer number.

```js
let T = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);

let taskId = T-100;
let taskCreaterName = 'mark';
let customerName = 'henry';

//assuming T-100 is a result of an expression, you would do something like:
console.log(`Task ${taskId} assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName}`);

//assming T-100 is a litral string, then you don't need to parse it at all
console.log(`Task T-100 assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String#replace` with custom callback and `eval` (`name` contains only chars `[a-zA-z0-9]` so it should be safe)

```js
var message = 'Task ${taskId} assigned by ${taskCreaterName} for customer ${customerName}';
let taskId = 'T-100';
let taskCreaterName = 'mark';
let customerName = 'henry';

var newMessage = message.replace(/\${([\w]+)}/g, function(match, name){
  return eval(name);
})

console.log(newMessage);
```